# Ifram on Sub Domain not storing the selected item data to cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, session, cookies, iframe

I have a php project on subdomain like new.expample.com which have a iframe of example.com/shop (which is WordPress site and I am using woocommerace ). when I try to add items into cart it say added but when I view the cart page its empty  . How I can fix it > . thanks in advance

Comment: Make sure that your browser allows third party cookies. This is something anyone visiting the site needs to enable though (which is usually not recommended)

Comment: How I can achieve that in Chrome ????

Comment: You start by google something like _"allow third party cookies chrome"_???? Please at least _try_ before you ask.